# Framework for Fast develoment of a graphic Win32 application

Tags: windows, telnet, rapid-prototyping

I am not a Windows programmer, more of an embedded engineer. But for some tests, I need to develop something fast for Windows users. Just a small program that will be ran on Windows XP and Windows 7.

That program will just have some buttons that will execute a script through telnet in a remote host (a development board).

What framework/language is fast to develop/learn for and has an easy telnet library?

I am experienced in C, Java, Bash, Perl, Python, and written some automation jobs in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can Windows Forms or WPF in .NET to develop this program quickly.